# Having trouble initializing a two-dimensional character array to all white space

Tags: c++, arrays, function, whitespace, multidimensional-array

When I use this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void InitBoard(char boardAr[][3])
{
    boardAr[3][3] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
}
```

I get this error:

> ```
> cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'char' in assignment
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a multidimensional array (c++) with values in following manner.

```
char boardAr[3][3] =
{
    {' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' '}
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an initialiser with assignment. You can only use an initialiser with an initialisation. What you are attempting to do is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
boardAr[3][3] = ...
```

is an assignment to the fourth column of the fourth row of boardAr. It's not an assignment to the array itself.

You can use memset or memcpy if you want to initialise an entire memory range to a known value efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void InitBoard(char boardAr[][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            boardAr[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

That is the proper way to initialize your array

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like 2D array in C, internally 2D array is a 1D array. considering this fact we can use memset() to initialize 2D array or any structure or anything that has continuous memory layout.  [please refer here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html)

```
void InitBoard(char boardAr[][3], const int row, const int col)
{
    memset(boardAr, ' ', sizeof(char)*row*col); // you can use any other value also, here we used ' '.  
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char arr[3][3];
    InitBoard(arr, 3,3); // It initialize your array with ' '
    return 0;
}
```